# How to use EfficientDet-Lite0 model from Mediapipe?

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

I have trouble in using efficientdet model from mediapipe without the mediapipe itself. I get correct predictions about whether there is a person on the image, but completely wrong coordinates.

I have downloaded this [model](https://storage.googleapis.com/mediapipe-models/object_detector/efficientdet_lite0/float16/latest/efficientdet_lite0.tflite)  and converted it with tf2onnx

Then i tried to use it with dnn module from OpenCV:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX('efficientdet_lite0.onnx')
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
img = cv2.imread('123.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (320,320))
net.setInput(img[np.newaxis, :]/255)
outputs=net.forward(net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())
box_list = outputs[0][0]
probability_list = outputs[1][0][:,0] ### Only first score in each row, becouse i need to predict
                                      ### persons on photos
```

With np.argmax i search for max index in probability_list:

```
idx = np.argmax(probability_list))
```

And at this stage everything works correct: on photos with people i get high scores (0.8 and higher) without persons low (lower then 0.3)

Then i tried to get coordinates from box_list like this way:

```
box = (box_list[idx]*320).astype(int)
```

But this doesn't work. I get absolutely wrong coordinates, sometimes with negative values.

Please, help.